# UDP socket on Universal Windows not receiving data

Tags: c#, sockets, networking, udp, win-universal-app

I have a WPF application that receives data through a UDP socket. Now I need to port it to Universal Windows Platform, but the socket does not receive the incoming data.

```
private void Init()
{
    socket = new Socket(SocketType.Dgram, ProtocolType.Udp);
    socket.Bind(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("192.168.0.1"), 55156));

    socketAsyncArgs = new SocketAsyncEventArgs();
    buffer = new byte[4096];
    socketAsyncArgs.SetBuffer(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
    socketAsyncArgs.Completed += Receive_Completed;
}

private void Receive()
{
    bool isPending = socket.ReceiveAsync(socketAsyncArgs);
    if ( ! isPending)
        Receive_Completed(socket, socketAsyncArgs);
}
```

The `Receive_Completed` method is never called. The same code works well in a WPF project. I used WireShark to verify the packets are coming. I also tried using `Windows.Networking.Sockets.DatagramSocket` with the same result - the socket does not receive any data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution. Apparently, you have to specifically enable that the application will be receiving incoming network traffic. The UWP project in Visual Studio contains a file named `Package.appxmanifest`. Double click it, select the Capabilities tab and check Internet (Client & Server). More about that at the [MSDN - Networking basics](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/networking/networking-basics).

Answer (score 0):

Don't you have to connect First? I dont about socket.bind but you have to set an `IPEndPoint` in `socketAsyncArgs.RemoteEndPoint`. And please don't call Receive_Completed!!! its an event it should be triggered automatically.

I tested you code with a server and worked(but in TCP and Stream mode)

```
private void Init()
{
    socket = new Socket(SocketType.Dgram, ProtocolType.Udp);

    socketAsyncArgs = new SocketAsyncEventArgs();
    socketAsyncArgs.RemoteEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("192.168.0.1"), 55156);
    buffer = new byte[4096];
    socketAsyncArgs.SetBuffer(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
    socketAsyncArgs.Completed += Receive_Completed;
}

private void Receive()
{
    bool isPending = socket.ConnectAsync(socketAsyncArgs);
    if (!isPending)
        isPending = socket.ReceiveAsync(socketAsyncArgs);
}
```

Comment: I want to receive data, not send, so I use `Bind` instead of `Connect`.

The `ReceiveAsync` may be executed asynchronously in which case the `Receive_Completed` even handler will be called. But it can also be executed synchronously in which case I have to call `Receive_Completed` myself. I agree the mechanism is queer.

I know the code works on WPF. I can't get it work in UWP.

Comment: Cause it work differently in UWP. Try this. Put a break point in Receive_Completed. Do ConnectAsync. You will see that it will break in Receive_Completed. Then do ReceiveAsync and some data from the server. You will see that it will break in Receive_Completed again.

Comment: Connect to my local address/port? I tried that, `Receive_Completed` is called, the receive buffer is empty. When I call `ReceiveAsync` then, the `Receive_Completed` is not called any more. I also tried connecting to the remote computer (whose IP/port I know just because it's my testing machine) with the same result.